# What does 'foo' really mean?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

I hope this qualifies as a programming question, as in any programming tutorial, you eventually come across 'foo' in the code examples. (yeah, right?)

what does 'foo' really mean?

If it is meant to mean **nothing**, when did it begin to be used so?

Comment: The question linked in the previous comment has apparently been deleted. It is still available in the unofficial archive of deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/262/271.html . see also this related deleted question: http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/163/229.html

Answer (score 139, accepted):

See: [RFC 3092: Etymology of "Foo", D. Eastlake 3rd et al.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3092)

Quoting only the relevant definitions from that RFC for brevity:

> 2. Used very generally as a sample name for absolutely anything, esp.
>    programs and files (esp. scratch files).

> 3. First on the standard list of metasyntactic variables used in
>    syntax examples (bar, baz, qux, quux, corge, grault, garply,
>    waldo, fred, plugh, xyzzy, thud). [JARGON]

Comment: Mark Tomlin, look at the date in that RFC.

Comment: RFC - "Request For Comments documents were invented by Steve Crocker in 1969 to help record unofficial notes on the development of the ARPANET. They have since become the official record for Internet specifications, protocols, procedures, and events". Source: [http://www.livinginternet.com](http://www.livinginternet.com/i/ia_rfc.htm)

Comment: Why use the term "foo" when a more informative term (like "test" or "temp") could be used? Maybe it's one of those cultural things - programmers feel using old jargon like foo gives them "street cred".

Comment: We're not here for brevity. The RFC also says
    "When used in connection with `bar' it is generally traced to the WW II era Army slang acronym FUBAR (`Fucked Up Beyond All Repair'), later modified to foobar."

Answer (score 44):

`foo` is used as a place-holder name, usually in example code to signify that the object being named, or the choice of name, is not part of the crux of the example. `foo` is often followed by `bar`, `baz`, and even `bundy`, if more than one such name is needed. Wikipedia calls these names [Metasyntactic Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). Python programmers supposedly use `spam`, `eggs`, `ham`, instead of `foo`, etc.

There are [good uses of foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683/using-in-to-match-an-attribute-of-python-objects-in-an-array#750) in SA.

I have also seen `foo` used when the programmer can't think of a meaningful name (as a substitute for `tmp`, say), but I consider that to be a misuse of `foo`.

Answer (score 22):

As definition of "Foo" has lot's of meanings:

- bar, and baz are often compounded together to make such words as foobar, barbaz, and foobaz.
  [www.nationmaster.com/encyclopedia/Metasyntactic-variable](http://www.nationmaster.com/encyclopedia/Metasyntactic-variable)
- Major concepts in CML, usually mapped directly onto XMLElements (to be discussed later).
  [wwmm.ch.cam.ac.uk/blogs/cml/](http://wwmm.ch.cam.ac.uk/blogs/cml/)
- Measurement of the total quantity of pasture in a paddock, expressed in kilograms of pasture dry matter per hectare (kg DM/ha)
  [www.lifetimewool.com.au/glossary.aspx](http://www.lifetimewool.com.au/glossary.aspx)
- Forward Observation Officer. An artillery officer who remained with infantry and tank battalions to set up observation posts in the front lines from which to observe enemy positions and radio the coordinates of targets to the guns further in the rear.
  [members.fortunecity.com/lniven/definition.htm](http://members.fortunecity.com/lniven/definition.htm)
- is the first metasyntactic variable commonly used. It is sometimes combined with bar to make foobar. This suggests that foo may have originated with the World War II slang term fubar, as an acronym for **f**ucked/**f**ouled **u**p **b**eyond **a**ll **r**ecognition, although the Jargon File makes a pretty good case ...
  [explanation-guide.info/meaning/Metasyntactic-variable.html](http://explanation-guide.info/meaning/Metasyntactic-variable.html)
- Foo is a metasyntactic variable used heavily in computer science to represent concepts abstractly and can be used to represent any part of a ...
  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOo)
- Foo is the world of dreams (no its not) in Obert Skye's Leven Thumps series. Although it has many original inhabitants, most of its current dwellers are from Reality, and are known as nits. ...
  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo (place)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo)
- Also foo’. Representation of fool (foolish person), in a Mr. T accent
  [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foo)

Resource: [google](http://google.com)

Comment: Great answer but probably worth put a link to Jargon file entry: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html

Comment: Google results aren't an answer

Comment: Google results aren't an answer<<I don't get. So then what is answer ? if you think of one ? with no guarantee ? or I should drop here actual links to mass of sites? I think that stackoverflow must have things in one place, not just links to other sites, that's way i posted all this into one thread.

Comment: Hey, if you're going to post all the non-programming related answers, why did you leave out "foo-fighter" the name WWII pilots gave to UFOs they saw and couldn't identify but presumed were enemy fighters?

Answer (score 11):

It's a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable).

Answer (score 10):

foo = File or Object. It is used in place of an object variable or file name.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's meant to mean nothing. The wiki says:

"Foo is commonly used with the metasyntactic variables bar and foobar."

Answer (score 3):

The sound of the french fou, (like: amour fou) [crazy] written in english, would be foo, wouldn't it. Else furchtbar -> foobar -> foo, bar -> barfoo -> barfuß (barefoot). Just fou. A foot without teeth.

I agree with all, who mentioned it means: nothing interesting, just something, usually needed to complete a statement/expression.

Comment: I like the comparison with other languages and their different meanings  :-D

Answer (score 3):

Among my colleagues, the meaning (or perhaps more accurately - the *use*) of the term "foo" has been to serve as a placeholder to represent an example for a *name*. Examples include, but not limited to, *yourVariableName*, *yourObjectName*, or *yourColumnName*.

Today, I avoid using "foo" and prefer using this type of *named* substitution for a couple of reasons.

- In my earlier days, I originally found the use of "foo" as a placement in any example to represent something as f'd-up to be confusing. I wanted a working example, not something that was foobar.
- Your results may vary, but I always, 100%, everytime, never-failed, got more follow-up questions about the meaning of the actual variable where "foo" was used.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion every programmer has his or her own "words" that is used every time you need an arbitrary word when programming. 
For some people it's the first words from a childs song, for other it's names and for other its something completely different.
Now for the programmer community there are these "words" as well, and these words are 'foo' and 'bar'.
The use of this is that if you have to communicate publicly about programming you don't have to say that you would use arbitratry words, you would simply write 'foo' or 'bar' and every programmer knows that this is just arbitrary words.

Comment: If "everybody" knows this, why are so many people asking about the meaning of "foo", "bar" and "foobar"? Prakash is not the first person to ask.

IMO foo, bar and foobar are not intuitive, like a, b, c, tmp, X, Y, Z, var and func, which is why I think many pe

Comment: Hm.. Is it just me, or is the rendering of long comments broken? Anyway, the rest was "... why I think many people find them distracting."

Comment: Yeah, you exceeded your 300 characters limit for a comment ;) but thanks!

Comment: I am probably just tangled too deep in the developer community ;-)

Comment: I found (and find) them distracting. Especially when first trying to decipher python, I took them to be far more meaningful than they are. Maybe a function, or some part of the syntax.
Though I had the same issue with things like **kwargs. I instinctively try to memorise stuff like that. To the point of writing it down. Until someone told me "it doesn't matter what phrase you use, as long as you have the ** ". At least "kwargs" makes sense when you realise what it stands for. Stuff like "foo" is just confusingly 'mystical'. They feel like injokes for the sake of injokes.