# Help with string manipulation function

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a set of strings that contain within them one or more question marks delimited by a comma, a comma plus one or more spaces, or potentially both.  So these strings are all possible:

```
BOB AND ?
BOB AND ?,?,?,?,?
BOB AND ?, ?, ? ,?
BOB AND ?,?  ,  ?,?
?,  ?               ,? AND BOB
```

I need to replace the question marks with `@P#`, so that the above samples would become:

```
BOB AND @P1
BOB AND @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5
BOB AND @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4
BOB AND @P1,@P2,@P3,@P4
@P1,@P2,@P3 AND BOB
```

What's the best way to do this without regex or Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ignored the trimming of spaces in your output example, because if this is to be used in a SQL statement, the spaces are irrelevent. This should perform pretty well due to the use of `StringBuilder` rather than repeated calls to `Replace`, `Substring`, or other string methods.:

```
public static string GetParameterizedString(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sArray = s.Split('?');
    for (var i = 0; i < sArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(sArray[i]);
        sb.Append("@P");
        sb.Append(i + 1);
    }
    sb.Append(sArray[sArray.Length - 1]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The spaces only affect my OCD, but mercifully I don't have to look at these queries. :)

Comment: LOL, hope my example was tidy enough.

Comment: In SQL Server (which this isn't) the spaces in a query like this *could* affect the execution plan caching. Two queries that differed only by spaces would not benefit from each other's cached plans (I'm pretty sure, anyway). </TRIVIA>

Comment: @Music: That's probably true, but suggests a lack of DRY, a bigger issue IMO.

Comment: My only tiniest of tiny issues would be with the second `var`, since the type returned by Split() is (arguably) not obvious. Moot point, since I'm stuck in C# 2.0. :)

Comment: I just realized that "you lack DRY" is like saying "you're all wet". :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want regex or LINQ, I would just write a loop, and use the "ReplaceFirst" method from this question to loop over the string, replacing each occurrence of ? with the appropriate @P#.\

[How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-net)

Maybe something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (myString.Contains("?"))
{
    myString = myString.ReplaceFirst("?", "@P" + i);
    i++;
}
```

Note that "ReplaceFirst" is not a standard method on string - you have to implement it (e.g. as an extension method, in this example).

Comment: LOL. I was kicking myself for having missed the `ReplaceFirst` method of `String` before I read the rest of your answer. Jeez, you want the check without doing any real work? :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate your SQL as you get your parameters defining proper CASE in your code and give it to execution at the very end when it is ready?

Comment: The SQL was already generated for a database that allows question marks for parameters, and we have to now use it with a database that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something out of the box :)

```
string toFormat = "?,  ?               ,? AND BOB";
while (toFormat.Contains("  "))
    toFormat = toFormat.Replace("  ", " ");
toFormat = toFormat.Replace("?", "{0}");
string formated = string.Format(toFormat, new PCounter());
```

Where PCounter is like this

```
class PCounter{
    int i = 0;
    public override string ToString(){
        return "@P" + (++i);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't realize that an arg's ToString method was called anew for each placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the below should do it.

```
string input = "BOB AND ?,?,?,?,?";
int number = 1;
int index = input.IndexOf("?");
while (index > -1)
{
    input = input.Substring(0, index).Trim() + " @P" + number++.ToString() + input.Substring(index + 1).Trim();
    index = input.IndexOf("?");
}
```