# add anchor tag before image tag

Tags: c#, string, image

I have one string:

```
string explanation= "Which of the following are associated with ependymitis " +
    "<img id='id=47148;displayStyle=Simple;width=100;height=62;loop=False;' " +
         "isMaintainAspectRatio=True "+ 
    "src='../Admin/GetImage.ashx?id=240648' alt='Image4' width='100' height='62' " + 
    "href='../Admin/GetImage.ashx?id=240648'/><br />";
```

I want to add `<a></a>` tag before the `<img>` tag. How can we do that when there are many `<img>` tags in explanation?

Comment: [img id='id=47148;displayStyle=Simple;width=100;height=62;loop=False; isMaintainAspectRatio=True] What is this gibberish? That's not even close to a proper image tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to turn this img "specification" into a clickable image link? You also obviously are doing additional processing on this string because that don't look like no img tag I've ever seen.

Comment: Have you checked out the HtmlAgilityPack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/?

Comment: Ping @user838804 - time to accept or post an update please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method:

```
explanation.Replace("<img", "<a></a><img");
```

Or, if you want to replace only the first occurence of the `<img>` tag (not sure what I should understand of your question), take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net).

Comment: awesome for answering exactly what is being asked.

Comment: I don't think this takes context of the question into account fully - although the OP says they want to add an "<a></a>" tag before an "<img>" tag, "<a></a>" will do nothing and "<img>" with its closing bracket does not exist in the markup.

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe: Well that's not in the question, is it? Maybe the OP knows what he wants to do with the string after the `Replace` operation.

Comment: Actually it does not work, the <img> tag in the example starts with "<img "

Comment: @Otiel given that you took the `"<img>"` part literally (yet corrected it when pointed out by @Teudimundo but not by me) I figured I may as well point out the `<a></a>` thing whilst I was at it :)