# Replace first occurrence of pattern in a string

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Let's say I have the string:

```
string s = "Hello world.";
```

how can I replace the first `o` in the word `Hello` for let's say `Foo`?

In other words I want to end up with:

```
"HellFoo world."
```

I know how to replace all the o's but I want to replace just the first one

Comment: Voted to re-open this old question, which as _explicitly about **pattern** and **regular expression**_. While it an be simplified in this case to literals strings, it is not technically same as the actual ask. Unfortunately the duplicate is also tagged with 'regex', although it does not include 'pattern' anywhere.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

I think you can use the overload of [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) to specify the maximum number of times to replace...

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("Hello World", "Foo", 1);
```

Comment: good option to replace

Answer (score 281):

```
public string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
{
  int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
  if (pos < 0)
  {
    return text;
  }
  return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
}
```

here is an Extension Method that could also work as well per `VoidKing` request

```
public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ReplaceFirst(this string text, string search, string replace)
    {
      int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
      if (pos < 0)
      {
        return text;
      }
      return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: much better than the regex imho, this is what the regex will eventually do anyway, after skipping overhead. In very long strings with the result very far at the end, the regex impl might be better as it supports streaming the char array, but for small strings, this seems a lot more efficient...

Comment: Never, ever do this. Use .Net.  (ie, use the regex call made for this purpose.)

Comment: @Fattie Care to explain why?

Comment: public static string ReplaceFirst(this string text, string search, string replace)
        {
            int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
            if (pos < 0)
            {
                return text;
            }
            string result = text.Remove(pos, search.Length).Insert(pos, replace);
            return result;
        }

Answer (score 17):

There are a number of ways that you could do this, but the fastest might be to use IndexOf to find the index position of the letter you want to replace and then substring out the text before and after what you want to replace.

```
if (s.Contains("o"))
{
    s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf('o')) + "Foo" + s.Substring(s.IndexOf('o') + 1);
}
```