# Replace the first occurrence in a string

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I have this string :

```
Hello my name is Marco
```

and I'd like to replace the first space (between `Hello` and `my`) with `<br />`. Only the first.

What's the best way to do it on C#/.NET 3.5?

Comment: You should have given it a go yourself. This is the type of situation that can be good fun to solve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to add substrings, following will find the first space instance only.
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx):

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified
> string in this instance.

```
  string x = "Hello my name is Marco";
  int index = x.IndexOf(" ");
  if (index >= 0)
  {
      x=x.Remove(index,1);
      x = x.Insert(index, @"<br />");
  }
```

**Edit:** If you are not sure if space will occur, some validations must come into place. I have edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I like the compacted version. But if the string don't have any space, I can't use it...)

Comment: @markzzz If you are not sure if space will occur, some validations must come into place. I have edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't replace the string but just inserts a new inputted string after the first occurrence of that string, So at the end x would be `Hello <br />my name is Marco` but it should be this `Hello<br />my name is Marco`.

Comment: -1, what @yogi said, there's a couple of working answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string

Comment: @Joe I have mentioned an edit also, so he can use switch case. I think my answer is not incorrect or out-of-the-context to get a down vote. Surprise !

Comment: The question is titled 'how do you *replace* the first occurance in a string', your solution is answering 'how do you *insert* an extra string at the first occurance'. E.g if he wanted to replace the word 'Marco' with another name, your answer will show the inserted name + Marco. Your edit doesn't solve what is essentially using the wrong function.

Answer (score 11):

```
 public static class MyExtensions
 {

   public static string ReplaceFirstOccurrance(this string original, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        return String.Empty;
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue))
        return original;
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
        newValue = String.Empty;
     int loc = original.IndexOf(oldValue);
     return original.Remove(loc, oldValue.Length).Insert(loc, newValue);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
string str="Hello my name is Marco";  
str.ReplaceFirstOccurrance("Hello", "<br/>");
str.ReplaceFirstOccurrance("my", "<br/>");
```

Comment: You should make this an extension method, then it'd be `"This is what is right".ReplaceFirstOccurance("is","<br/>")`

Comment: I know extension methods but y should this to be Extension Method, this can be used as it is. but yes if you want you can convert it to Extension Method.

Comment: Because this method is specific to a string, so as a general rule should be extended onto an instance of a string, rather than `SomeUtilityClass.ReplaceFirstOccurance`. Its exactly what extension methods are for!

Answer (score 3):

```
string tmp = "Hello my name is Marco";
int index = tmp.IndexOf(" ");
tmp = tmp.Substring(0, index) + "<br />" + tmp.Substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this would work:

```
var s = "Hello my name is Marco";
var firstSpace = s.IndexOf(" ");
var replaced = s.Substring(0,firstSpace) + "<br/>" + s.Substring(firstSpace+1);
```

You could make this into an extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(this string input, string find, string replace){
  var first= s.IndexOf(find);
  return s.Substring(0,first) + replace + s.Substring(first+find.Length);
}
```

And then the usage would be

```
var s = "Hello my name is Marco";
var replaced = s.ReplaceFirst(" ","<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str = "Hello my name is Marco".Split(' ');
string newstr = str[0] + "<br /> " + string.Join(" ", str.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

> ```
> Replace("Hello my name is Marco", " ", "<br />", 1, 1)
> ```