# How can I replace a word at a specific index while returning the whole string?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to replace a specific word in my program with a repetition asterixes.

Here is my current function:
Word is the word being replaced.

```
mystring = tbText.text
mystring = Replace(mystring, word, "***", 5, 1)
```

The issue here is the fact that mystring returns just the replaced word rather than returning the entire string, reasoning for this being, the word at index 5 and ending in index 10 is only being returned due to the minimum index and maximum index set.

Is there another function I can use to replace the specific word while returning the entire string with the word replaced?

Comment: may i see one example

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do?  As you will see from the answers, there is confusion.

Comment: I'm looking to have a loop that checks if the word in the string is to be removed, if a removal is required that word must be replaced with asterixs

Answer (score 1):

Take off the 4th and 5th parameters.

```
mystring = tbText.text
mystring = Replace(mystring, word, "***")
```

UPDATE: Having done my research properly, what the OP wants is to change the 4th parameter to 1, like so;

```
mystring = Replace(mystring, word, "***", 1, 1)
```

As the documentation explains, this will return the original string starting from position 1 (parameter 4) and only make 1 replacement (parameter 5).

Hopefully we can now all agree that the OPs requirements are satisfied - even though it's many years later!

Comment: That will replace all instance of word.

Comment: The OP isn't exactly clear about whether they want all instances replaced or not.  I interpreted it as 'hiding' all the occurrences of the word, since it's being replaced with asterisks.

Comment: The original code explains the OP is replacing first instance.

Comment: @doker This has reared it's head nearly 5 years later - can you let me know if we are now in agreement?  Hopefully the update will explain how the function works for any future visitors!

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));
var newText = regex.Replace("Hello World", "Foo", 1);
```

[Replace first occurrence of pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

I think I never used a `Start` parameter different from 0 so I never noticed that *"the return value of the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function is a string that begins at the position specified by `Start` and concludes at the end of the `Expression` string, with the substitutions made as specified by the `Find` and `Replace` values."*

Try this code to solve your problem:

```
Dim strWord As String = "6"
Dim strNewWord As String = "*****"

Dim strTest As String = "1234567890"

MsgBox(Strings.Left(strTest, strTest.IndexOf(strWord)) & _
    Replace(strTest, strWord, strNewWord, strTest.IndexOf(strWord) + 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StringBuilder` Class for this

```
Dim mystring As String = "This is my String"
Dim word As String = "my"

Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(mystring)
sb.Replace(word, "***", 8, 2)
Dim newstring As String = sb.ToString()
```

Now `newstring` is set to `This is *** String`