# How can I edit particular word one by one in a text line?

Tags: c#, string, editing

Let's say I have a text:

"His name is Jack. Jack likes to ride a bike"

What method would you recommend using to edit word "Jack" one by one, for example, I want to make specific changes for each "Jack". I've tried using Remove() and Replace(), but these methods edit all "Jack" in the text.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) may be what you need. In the specified input string, it replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a string returned by a [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate.
So your MatchEvaluator delegate can decide what to replace every single "Jack" with.
For example:

```
string s = "His name is Jack. Jack likes to ride a bike";
int count = 0;
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, "Jack", match => {
    count++;
    return count > 1 ? "Jack2" : "Jack1";
});
```

s2 is:

> His name is Jack1. Jack2 likes to ride a bike