# Replace first occurrence of 0 from string consisting of both numbers and letters

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to remove first 0 from integer part of the string. 
IF `"CATI-09100"` has `0` first in `interger` part remove it and string would be `"CATI-9100"`. Otherwise no change. I tried using `substring`. But I need better and efficient way to do it. Also, `"CATI-"` will be in every string. Any hint will do.

I was thinking on below lines :

```
strICTOID = Convert.ToString(drData.GetValue(0).Equals(System.DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : drData.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim());
            if (strICTOID.Length > 0)
            {
                indexICTO = strICTOID.IndexOf("-");


            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the first 0 from integer part of the string?  That is, if your string is "CATI-9102", do you really want it to return "CATI-912"?  Maybe you just want to remove the leading zeros.  What if there are two leading zeros - "CATI-0020" - do you want "CATI-020" or "CATI-20"?

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple string replace.

```
string text = "CATI-09100";

string newText = text.Replace("-0", "-"); // CATI-9100
```

Comment: Don't we need to check whether 0 exists first or not?

Comment: So that it doesn't break for those strings which doesn't contain 0. Although your solution is easy and simple. like it

Comment: It will not change the string if it did not find the zero

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this-

```
string check = indexICTO.Split('-')[1]; // will split by "-"
    if(check[0].Equals("0"))            // will check if the charcter after "-" is 0 or not
        indexICTO  = indexICTO.Replace("-0", "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove all the zeros at the begining of an integer you can do this:

```
your_string = Regex.Replace(your_string, @"-0+(\d+)", "$1");
//CATI-009100 -->  CATI-9100
//CATI-09100  -->  CATI-9100
//CATI-9100   -->  CATI-9100
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [Replace first occurrence of pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string)

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("0"));
var newText = regex.Replace("CATI-09100", "", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rookie way but sure works.

```
        string myString , firstPart,secondPart ;
        int firstNumValue;


         myString = "CATI-09994";
         string[] parts = myString.Split('-');
         firstPart = parts[0];
         secondPart = parts[1];

        firstNumValue = int.Parse(secondPart.Substring(0, 1));

        if(firstNumValue == 0){
            secondPart =  secondPart.Remove(0,1);
        } 

        Console.WriteLine(firstPart+"-"+secondPart);
```