# Replace words in a string one by one using C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to *replace words* in a `string` using C#. Every time, I would like to get *one* matched word replaced.

**Example:**

`"This is example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3."`

Let's *replace* `"is"` with `"###"` *one by one*, then we should get **3** strings:

**Desired outcome:**

1. `"This ### example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3."`
2. `"This is example 1, this ### example 2, that is example 3."`
3. `"This is example 1, this is example 2, that ### example 3."`

**===== update =====**

I'm new to Stack Overflow and thanks all for helping!

I was searching for match collection but didn't know how to replace word **from a certain index** (word matched index), so I ask this question. Thanks Dmitry for Linq solution and modifying the description of this question! Also thanks Anu for your solution!

Comment: Hint: Using RegEx you would have a Matches collection.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and C#. Yes, i was searching for MatchCollection, thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *query* the `source` string with a help of *Linq* while *matching* whole `word` of interest with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source =
  @"This is example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3";

string word = "is";

string[] result = Regex
  .Matches(source, $@"\b{Regex.Escape(word)}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => 
     $"{source.Substring(0, match.Index)}###{source.Substring(match.Index + match.Length)}")
  .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look at `result` array:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
This ### example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3
This is example 1, this ### example 2, that is example 3
This is example 1, this is example 2, that ### example 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex and [MatchCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(string originalText,string wordToReplace)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex($" {wordToReplace} ",RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(originalText);

    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder(originalText);
        strBuilder.Remove(match.Index,match.Length);
        strBuilder.Insert(match.Index," ### ");
        yield return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Sample Output

```
This ### example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3. 
This is example 1, this ### example 2, that is example 3. 
This is example 1, this is example 2, that ### example 3
```

Comment: Sorry, what is `matches.Dump();`, please?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sorry, was attempting it from Linqpad. Forgot to remove it. Has updated the answer now :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
      String str = "This is example 1, this is example 2, that is example 3.";
      while(str.Contains("is") ) {
        str.Replace("is", "###")
        Console.WriteLine (str);
      }
  }
}
```

This code runs until the string doesn't contain anymore "is" strings and each iteration it replaces one and outputs the current string.

Comment: 1. `str.Replace("is", "###")` replaces all `is` in the first "iteration" 2. the return value of `str.Replace("is", "###")` needs to be assigned somewhere

Comment: True. We can use the functions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string or here: https://lonewolfonline.net/replace-first-occurrence-string/ to do that