# replace a character in a string in c# based on position with a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to replace a charecter in a string with a string in c#.
I have tried the following,

Here in the following program, i want replace set of charecters between charecters ':' and first occurance of '-' with some others charecters.

I could able to extract the set of charecters between ':' and first occurance of '-'.

Can any one say how to insert these back in the source string.

```
        string source= "tcm:7-426-8";
        string target= "tcm:10-15-2";
        int fistunderscore = target.IndexOf("-");
        string temp = target.Substring(4, fistunderscore-4);
        Response.Write("<BR>"+"temp1:" +   temp + "<BR>");
```

Examples:

```
        source: "tcm:7-426-8" or "tcm:100-426-8" or "tcm:10-426-8"

        Target: "tcm:10-15-2" or "tcm:5-15-2" or "tcm:100-15-2"

        output: "tcm:10-426-8" or "tcm:5-426-8" or "tcm:100-426-8"
```

In a nutshell, I want to replace the set of charectes between ':' and '-'(firstoccurance) and the charecters extracetd from the same sort of string.

Can any help how it can be done.

Thank you.

Comment: Your examples seem to be replacing the sub-string between the two hyphens (-); this does does not match your description of what you want.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regex solution - first this method, takes the `source` and `target` strings, and performs a regex replace on the first, targetting the first numbers after the 'tcm', which must be anchored to the start of the string.  In the `MatchEvaluator` it executes the same regex again, but on the `target` string.

```
static Regex rx = new Regex("(?<=^tcm:)[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public string ReplaceOneWith(string source, string target)
{
    return rx.Replace(source, new MatchEvaluator((Match m) =>
    {
        var targetMatch = rx.Match(target);
        if (targetMatch.Success)
            return targetMatch.Value;
        return m.Value; //don't replace if no match
    }));
}
```

Note that no replacement is performed if the regex doesn't return a match on the target string.

Now run this test (probably need to copy the above into the test class):

```
[TestMethod]
public void SO9973554()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("tcm:10-426-8", ReplaceOneWith("tcm:7-426-8", "tcm:10-15-2"));
    Assert.AreEqual("tcm:5-426-8", ReplaceOneWith("tcm:100-426-8", "tcm:5-15-2"));
    Assert.AreEqual("tcm:100-426-8", ReplaceOneWith("tcm:10-426-8", "tcm:100-15-2"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the first ":Number-" from the source with the content from target, you can use the following regex.

```
    var pattern1 = New Regex(":\d{1,3}-{1}");
    if(pattern1.IsMatch(source) && pattern1.IsMatch(target))
    {
        var source = "tcm:7-426-8";
        var target = "tcm:10-15-2";

        var res = pattern1.Replace(source, pattern1.Match(target).Value);
        // "tcm:10-426-8"
    }
```

Edit: To not have your string replaced with something empty, add an if-clause before the actualy replacing.

Comment: what if there's no match in `target`?

Comment: Then, the source match will be replaced with an empty string. Added some check before the regex. Thanks for the hint- input validation wasn't in my scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the logic used to decide which bit from which string is used, but still, you should use `Split()`, rather than mucking about with string offsets:
(note that the Remove(0,4) is there to remove the tcm: prefix)

```
string[] source = "tcm:90-2-10".Remove(0,4).Split('-');
string[] target = "tcm:42-23-17".Remove(0,4).Split('-');
```

Now you have the numbers from both `source` and `target` in easy-to-access arrays, so you can build the new string any way you want:

```
string output = string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}-{2}", source[0], target[1], source[2]);
```

Comment: Based on the examples the code should be `string output = string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}-{2}", target[0], source[1], source[2]);`

Comment: Possibly. It's a bit vague, and the three examples don't match. But it doesn't matter - I'm not here to give the OP the exact method to copy-paste into his code, but to give a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Heres without regex

```
string source = "tcm:7-426-8";
string target = "tcm:10-15-2";
int targetBeginning = target.IndexOf("-");
int sourceBeginning = source.IndexOf("-");
string temp = target.Substring(0, targetBeginning);//tcm:10
string result = temp + source.Substring(sourceBeginning, source.Length-sourceBeginning); //tcm:10 + -426-8
```