# Replace first time a combination of chars occur in a string VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, replace

I'm trying to replace the "00" that might come from a phone number when a user enters the number. And of course I only want the first 00 to get replaced with a + sign. In Java there is  the method:

```
result.replaceFirst("00", "+");
```

Is there anything like that in .NET?
Or is there any smart way to do this in vb.NET?

Comment: Surely you only want to do that replacement if the string *starts* with "00" - not just wherever the first occurrence of these digits appear in the string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enigmativity's is a cool 1 liner. You can also try this..

```
    if(result.StartsWith("00"))
       result= result.Replace(result.Substring(0, 2), "+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var clean = text.StartsWith("00") ? "+" + text.Substring(2) : text;
```