# Finding all instances of a quote in a C# string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find and replace all instances of a double quote in a C# string using regex, but can't quite seem to grasp the answer, here is what I have so far:

```
private string checkEscapeChars(string s)
{
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[""]", String.Empty);
    return s;
}
```

Now, that runs okay, but lets say I have a string "this is my "Sample string"

I want to get rid of the " before Sample. Will the above work for that? Or will it find and replace all instances of matching double quotes, rather than single double quotes?

Comment: It looks like this was asked before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net

Comment: plz be clear with your question.....cant understand a thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why would you want to use a regular expression for this? Just use `String.Replace`:

```
withoutQuotes = withQuotes.Replace("\"", "");
```