# how to parse this comma delimited string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"'2014' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'"
```

I would like to join Position 1 and 2 together and save it back in position 1, for example:

```
"'2014381' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'"
```

Comment: And also, what did you search for before asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "'2014' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'";
var parts = str.Split(new string[] { " , " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

parts[0] = String.Format("'{0}{1}'", parts[0].Replace("'", ""),
                                     parts[1].Replace("'", ""));
str = String.Join(" , ", parts);
```

Comment: simple and smart. Thanks! there's only a space b/w the two which shouldn't be there, I should be able to remove that! Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.Split` and the `String.Join`:

```
string text = "'2014' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'";
string[] words = text.Split(new[] { "' , '" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string result = string.Join("", words.Take(2)) + 
                string.Join("' , '", words);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/71LCG6)

Answer (score 0):

Using the replaceFirst function noted in this question:

[How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

```
string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
{
  int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
  if (pos < 0)
  {
    return text;
  }
  return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
}
```

You could then do:

```
string updated = ReplaceFirst(original, "' , '", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "'2014' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'";
var delimeter = " , ";

var splits = input.Split(',').Select (i => i.Trim());
var result = splits.Take(2).Aggregate ((x, y) => x + y).Replace("''", "") 
    + delimeter + splits.Skip(1).Aggregate ((x, y) => x + delimeter + y);
```

Output:

```
'2014381' , '381' , '1' , 'Eastern 10' , 'Wes 10' , '1'
```