# Replace one word with different values

Tags: c#

I have a string "{Day} - is a victory day. {Day} - is my birthday";

How to replace {Day} with different numbers? I try:

```
string text = "{Day} - is a victory day. {Day} - is my birthday";
if (text.Contains("{Day}"))
    text = text.Replace("{Day}", xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString());
```

But day is the same in 2 replacements.

Comment: What is `xNet.Rand`? if it creates a new `Random` each time then this is your problem.

Comment: You need to replace them one by one like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/141076/360211

Comment: They're basically saying `Rand.Next()` is being executed once, and they want it executed for each occurrence of `{Day}`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Sorry for my bad english but who are  *`they`*?

Comment: @I4V - The person who posted this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Regex.Replace` with `MatchEvaluator` delegate:

```
string text = "{Day} - is a victory day. {Day} - is my birthday";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\{Day\}", m => xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.Replace` takes a string as a "replace with" parameter and replaces all occurrences with that. For example, in your case, Rand may generate the string `19` *once*, which is then passed in to Replace and will replace all occurrences of `{Day}`.

If you want it to generate a new replacement for each match, you can use `Regex.Replace` instead, it can take a function/lambda that is called once per match to generate the replacement string;

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, Regex.Escape("{Day}"),
        match => xNet.Rand.Next(1,30).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString()` only gets called once. That is, when `text.Replace(..)` fires.

To replace each occurance with a different number, you could do something like:

```
string searchString = "{Day}";
int foundIndex = text.IndexOf(searchString);
while (foundIndex > -1)
{
  text = text.Substring(0, foundIndex) 
           + xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString() 
           + text.Substring(foundIndex + searchString.Length);
  foundIndex = text.IndexOf(searchString);
}
```

Untested, but this should give you a clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the related (String.Replace) MSDN entry:

> Returns a new string in which **all occurrences** of a specified
>   Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with
>   another specified Unicode character or String.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Notice that it replaces **all** occurences. On your current code, you are replacing both occurences with the same randomly generated value.

Two possible solutions:

- Split the original string into two: Replace the value in the first, then in the second: and then concatenate both again.
- Rename the first {Day} parameter to, say, {Day0}; and the second to {Day1}. Then generate a random value for each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `Rand.Next` is evaluated only once, so the same value will be replaced.

You can do it with regex or manually:

```
string text = "{Day} - is a victory day. {Day} - is my birthday";
var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
while (text.Contains("{Day}"))
{
  int p=text.IndexOf("{Day}");
  sb.Remove(p,5);
  sb.Insert(p, xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString());
  text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do what you are trying to do... BUT you at least need to understand that you are only calling the `text.Replace()` method once, and it is working as expected.  I.E. replacing each instance of `{Day}` with the number the method generates.  If you want them to be two different values you need to replace two different values.

```
    string text = "{Day} - is a victory day.  {Day2} - is my birthday";
    text = text.Replace("{Day}", xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString());
    text = text.Replace("{Day2}", xNet.Rand.Next(1, 30).ToString());
```

Comment: P.S. I realize this is sloppy... just trying to keep the answer in the context of the question.  Which is also sloppy ;)