# Length of substring matched by culture-sensitive String.IndexOf method

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, substring

I tried writing a culture-aware string replacement method:

```
public static string Replace(string text, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    return index >= 0
        ? text.Substring(0, index) + newValue + text.Substring(index + oldValue.Length)
        : text;
}
```

However, it chokes on Unicode combining characters:

```
// \u0301 is Combining Acute Accent
Console.WriteLine(Replace("déf", "é", "o"));       // 1. CORRECT: dof
Console.WriteLine(Replace("déf", "e\u0301", "o")); // 2. INCORRECT: do
Console.WriteLine(Replace("de\u0301f", "é", "o")); // 3. INCORRECT: dóf
```

To fix my code, I need to know that in the second example, `String.IndexOf` matched only one character (`é`) even though it searched for two (`e\u0301`). Similarly, I need to know that in the third example, `String.IndexOf` matched two characters (`e\u0301`) even though it only searched for one (`é`).

How can I determine the actual length of the substring matched by [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)?

**NOTE:** Performing Unicode normalization on `text` and `oldValue` (as suggested by James Keesey) would accommodate combining characters, but ligatures would still be a problem:

```
Console.WriteLine(Replace("œf", "œ", "i"));  // 4. CORRECT: if
Console.WriteLine(Replace("œf", "oe", "i")); // 5. INCORRECT: i
Console.WriteLine(Replace("oef", "œ", "i")); // 6. INCORRECT: ief
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to directly call [FindNLSString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FindNLSStringEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) yourself. `String.IndexOf` uses [FindNLSStringEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but all the information you need is available in [FindNLSString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is an example of how to rewrite your Replace method that works against your test cases. Note that I am using the current user locale read up the API documentation if you want to use the system locale or provide your own. I am also passing in 0 for the flags which means it will use the default string comparison options for the locale, again the documentation can help you provide different options.

```
public const int LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = 0x0400;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern int FindNLSString(int locale, uint flags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string sourceString, int sourceCount, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string findString, int findCount, out int found);

public static string ReplaceWithCombiningCharSupport(string text, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    int foundLength;
    int index = FindNLSString(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, text, text.Length, oldValue, oldValue.Length, out foundLength);
    return index >= 0 ? text.Substring(0, index) + newValue + text.Substring(index + foundLength) : text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I spoke too soon (and had never seen this method before) but there is an alternative. You can use the [StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.parsecombiningcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the start of each actual character and use that to determine the length of the string to replace.

---

You will need to normalize both strings before you do the Index call. This will make sure that the source and target strings are the same length.

See the [String.Normalize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) reference page which describes this exact problem.

Comment: I don't want to normalize characters that aren't subject to replacement.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Why not? It represents the same text.

Comment: @TimS.: If the user has consciously chosen to enter the original text in a particular way, I'd rather not mess with that choice.

Comment: If you read the documentation for Normalize you will find out that there is no other way (in the libraries) to do this. If you really do not want to normalize the string then you will have to roll your own. Find the start of the string and then match each character allowing for combining characters until you find out the true length.

Comment: @JamesKeesey: Could you please point out exactly where the doc says "there is no other way"? I guess I'm not seeing it.

Comment: First paragraph under the Remarks for Normalize "implies" that it cannot be done. But I edited my original comment with another method I found that should give you an alternative that might work.

Comment: It turns out that normalization isn't sufficient anyway. For example, it doesn't handle ligatures: `OE` = `Œ`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following methods works for your examples. It works by comparing values until it finds how many characters are needed in the source string to equal the `oldValue`, and using that instead of simply `oldValue.Length`.

```
public static string Replace(string text, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    if (index >= 0)
        return text.Substring(0, index) + newValue +
                 text.Substring(index + LengthInString(text, oldValue, index));
    else
        return text;
}
static int LengthInString(string text, string oldValue, int index)
{
    for (int length = 1; length <= text.Length - index; length++)
        if (string.Equals(text.Substring(index, length), oldValue,
                                            StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
            return length;
    throw new Exception("Oops!");
}
```

Comment: I was afraid I had to do something like this. Internally, `String.IndexOf` must know how many characters it matched, but I'm surprised there's no (obvious?) way to get that information.

Comment: The LengthInString loop should count downwards. The match can be *longer* than `oldValue`. We probably should obtain the longest possible match.

Comment: `for (int length = 1; length < text.Length - index; length++)` should be `for (int length = 1; length <= text.Length - index; length++)` - eg. if text.Length is 3 and index is 2 the loop does nothing, but it should iterate once.

Comment: @JimW Thanks! I didn't realize that. I've fixed that in my answer. Off-by-one errors are my nemesis..