# Convert Do Until loop from VB to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to convert the VB code to c#

```
Do Until MarkerPos = 0 Or i > UBound(Values)
    s = Replace(s, Token, Values(i),  , 1)
    i = i + 1;
    MarkerPos = Strings.InStr(s, Token);
Loop
```

and I have converted it to do while

```
do
{
    s = Replace(s, Token, Values(i),  , 1)
    i = i + 1;
    MarkerPos = Strings.InStr(s, Token);
} while(MarkerPos = 0 || i > UBound(Values));
```

is it correct and is there any similar related to **UBound** in c#.???

Comment: What are you trying to do - I think you can probably do it better, if you explain the goal

Comment: "Do Until ..." is similar to a while(!(...)). Also, flip your while logic at the begining, not the end of the loop.

Comment: i dunno why am getting this negative points..! Answers are being posted too

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `values.Length` to return the number of items in a C# array:

```
do
{
    s = Replace(s, Token, Values(i),  , 1)
    i = i + 1;
    MarkerPos = Strings.InStr(s, Token);
} 
while(MarkerPos = 0 || i > Values.Length -1);
```

(You can also use `.Count()` for any other enumerable type)

EDIT:

Also - I think  your condition may be the wrong way around:

```
i < Values.Length -1
```

EDIT2:

and your logic should probably be an AND:

```
while(MarkerPos = 0 && i < Values.Length-1);
```

Comment: UBound = "upper bound", so yes

Comment: @Arshad: UBound is equal to Length or Count *less one*.  UBound is the highest index of the array, which is *not* the length.

Comment: I don't think you can use `do ... while`.  In that case, the code inside the loop will execute at least one time whereas in the original VB code, there is the possibility that the code won't execute at all.

Answer (score 1):

if you have an array of 10 items, `Ubound` will return 10 and `Length` will return 11.

you can use  `.GetUpperBound(0)` or `.Lenght-1`

proof

```
 using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ar = new string[11];

            Console.WriteLine(ar.GetUpperBound(0));
            Console.WriteLine(ar.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.UBound(ar));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

so with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141076/40868)

this is what you would need, I think

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "123412341234";
            string Token = "2";
            var Values = new string[] {"a","b", "c" };
            int i = 0;
            int MarkerPos;

            do
            {
                s = ReplaceFirst(s, Token, Values[i]);
                MarkerPos = s.IndexOf(Token);
                i++;
            } while(MarkerPos != -1 && i <= Values.GetUpperBound(0));

            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
        {
            int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
            if (pos < 0)
            {
                return text;
            }
            return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by 'the_lotus', the loop that is the most natural equivalent is a "while ( ! " loop:

```
while (!(MarkerPos == 0 || i > Values.GetUpperBound(0)))
{
    s = ...
    i = i + 1;
    MarkerPos = (s.IndexOf(Token) + 1);
}
```

Note that I've left out the 'Replace' equivalent - the version of the VB 'Replace' method that you are using has no direct equivalent, but you can likely verify whether the regular string 'Replace' method will be adequate or not.

Answer (score -1):

No ubound in c#. You can use something like Values.Length where Values is your string array.

Comment: No strictly true. You can use Ubound in the VisualBasic namespace if you add a reference to it.

Comment: Note that 'UBound' gives the highest index, which is different from 'Length' (UBound = Length - 1).

Answer (score -1):

You can write:

```
do
{
    ...
} while(MarkerPos != 0 && i < Values.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this page several time, it can convert vice versa: [Convert vb.net to c# or c# to vb.net - developerfusion.com](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

It also supports python and ruby.