# Combine date and time values and insert it into database in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

This is my query,

```
string sdatevalue = mysdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // "2014-02-12"
string stime = txttime.Text;  // 9.00 A.M

replace 9.00 to 9:00 = correcttime;


finaldate=sdatevalue + correcttime;
```

How to achieve this.

Thanks i want this to be done in asp.net C#

Comment: Where is your _query_? In general, use sql-parameters with the correct type instead of string concatenation with formatted strings. This prevents several issues, the most important is sql-injection.

Comment: I am using stored procedure for already my date is there in table just want to update the time 00:00:00 as my input time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be inserting this into a DataBase which is not a correct approach, its better you do it in your DB itself.

Create a method or extension

```
string ReplaceFirstOccurenceofCharacter(string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
        if (pos < 0)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    }
```

and call the method

```
        string sdatevalue = "2014-02-12";
        string stime = "9.00 A.M";
        string concatinatedstring = string.Format("{0} {1}", sdatevalue, stime);
        var result = ReplaceFirstOccurenceofCharacter(concatinatedstring, ".", ":");
```

Actual code is pulled from [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net) Hope it helps you.