# .net regex to replace newline with a space

Tags: regex

Please help me to make this work.
I have several .txt files and each one starts with:

```
<TABLE class="meta-attributes__table" border="0" cellspacing="0" 
cellpadding="0">
```

I need to replace only the first newline in each file so that the result to look like this

[image]

but without touching the rest of the newlines in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace the \*first instance\* of a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:              `^([^\n]*)\n`

Replace:           `$1`

Use `verbatinum` mode with `@`.