# How to replace string with dynamic value in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
string a = "**MustbeReplaced**asdgasfsff**MustbeReplaced**asdfafasfsa";
//MustbeReplaced should be Replaced1, Replaced2, and so on
a = a.Replace("MustbeReplaced", "Replaced");
```

Every time there is a string replacement, I would like to replace it with a dynamic value. For instance, the output of above string should be:

```
"**Replaced1**asdgasfsff**Replaced2**asdfafasfsa"
```

I know about [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx), but to the best of my knowledge, it's only for static `String` replacement.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Find first occurrence with `IndexOf`, replace, find next occurrence starting at previous position + replacement length, repeat until `IndexOf` returns `-1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace the \*first instance\* of a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Comment: Break the string into string array using key "MustbeReplaced" as seperator. Then run for loop on array.

Comment: @Esko No, I suppose that's a different case. In my case, I need to not only replace the first occurrence, but also all the occurrences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Regex` class and provide a delegate that will be called once for each match. It needs to return the string to replace the matched text with.

You simply have to declare a variable holding your counter:

```
string a = "**MustbeReplaced**asdgasfsff**MustbeReplaced**asdfafasfsa";
int replacementIndex = 0;
string b = Regex.Replace(a, "MustbeReplaced", match =>
{
    replacementIndex++;
    return $"Replaced{replacementIndex}";
});
```

After running this, `b` will contain this:

```
**Replaced1**asdgasfsff**Replaced2**asdfafasfsa
```

**Caution:** Since you're now using the `Regex` class, be aware of all the special characters that `Regex` will use to augment the pattern away from simple character-by-character matching. If you're replacing text containing symbols like asterixes, question marks, parenthesis, etc. then you need to escape those.

Luckily we can simply ask the `Regex` class to do that for us:

```
string a = "**Mustbe?Replaced**asdgasfsff**Mustbe?Replaced**asdfafasfsa";
int replacementIndex = 0;
string b = Regex.Replace(a, Regex.Escape("Mustbe?Replaced"), match =>
{
    replacementIndex++;
    return $"Replaced{replacementIndex}";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)` overload. The [corresponding MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an example which almost exactly matches your requirement.

Here's an even simpler example:

```
var input = "MustBeReplaced A MustBeReplaced B";

int i = 1;
MatchEvaluator evaluator = (m) => "Replaced " + (i++);

// yields Replaced 1 A Replaced 2 B
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "MustBeReplaced", evaluator);
```

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Oh, of course, thanks. And +1 to you for mentioning Escape!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use regex as already shown or this more efficient but less readable pure string methods approach:

```
string a = "**MustbeReplaced**asdgasfsff**MustbeReplaced**asdfafasfsa";
int matchCount = 0, index = 0;
while ((index = a.IndexOf("MustbeReplaced", index, StringComparison.Ordinal)) >= 0)
{
    a = a.Remove(index, "MustbeReplaced".Length).Insert(index, "Replaced" + ++matchCount);
}
```

Comment: Why is this more efficient?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: because string methods are more efficient than regex

Comment: Wouldn't this then be far better with the use of a `StringBuilder` as well?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: it depends. I've tested the regex approach with mine and there is less difference than i've thought. Regex needed 400 millis whereas the string-method approach needed 292 milliseconds on 100000 calls.

Comment: My tests showed the exact opposite. I doubled the string 5 times to generate a starting input of 1824 characters, on my machine the regex version ran in 5 milliseconds, the remove/insert loop in 19, with 100 iterations. A regex is table-driven for this kind of basic pattern matching and the Regex.Replace method uses a StringBuilder internally to build up the result so this doesn't really surprise me. I think GC is killing the remove/insert version.

Comment: The regex will perform better the longer the string is. So a StringBuilder approach would be better if it exceeds a certain length, say 200 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like:

```
        string source = "**MustbeReplaced**asdgasfsff**MustbeReplaced**asdfafasfsa";
        int count = 0;
        var result = Regex.Replace(source, "MustbeReplaced", m => "Replaced" + (++count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to avoid Regex? Want more performance? Use this code.
This code uses only at one time a StringBuilder.

```
    public static string ReplaceWithNumberPrefix(this string source, string oldString, string newString, int numberPrefixStart)
    {
        var oldStringLength = oldString.Length;

        var indexes = new List<int>();
        var p = source.IndexOf(oldString);                    
        if (p >= 0)
            do
            {
                indexes.Add(p);
                p = source.IndexOf(oldString, p + 1);                    
            } while (p >= 0);

        var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(source);
        var trailingDifference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
        {
            var replacement = string.Concat(newString, numberPrefixStart);
            var startIndex = indexes[i] + trailingDifference;
            builder.Replace(oldString, replacement, startIndex, oldStringLength);

            numberPrefixStart++;
            trailingDifference = trailingDifference + replacement.Length - oldStringLength;
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```