# Replace multiples words in text document C#

Tags: c#, text, document

So I'm trying to get a program running to save me copying and pasting loads of text for android studio. For this I have created listboxes with all the different bits of information required, added button click event to create a document, and another button click event to add the text into the document. So far I'm able to generate all the text when adding one set of latlongs, but I can't seem to work out how to add another set latlongs in..
For example

I need:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.79940000000, 31.01680000000)).title(bbb));

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.80150000000, 
31.03650000000)).title(ccc));
```

But all's I am getting is:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.79940000000, 31.01680000000)).title(bbb));

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-17.80150000000, 31.01680000000)).title(bbb));
```

The Longitude value is not changing? I'm hoping all of this makes sense?

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "latlong.txt";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.CreateText(path);
            MessageBox.Show("File has been created.");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter stwr = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                stwr.WriteLine("googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(" + listBox1.Items[i] + ", " + "ii" + ")).title(" + "bbb" + "));");
            }
            stwr.Close();
            string text = File.ReadAllText("latlong.txt");
            for (int ii = 0; ii < listBox2.Items.Count; ii++)
            {

                text = text.Replace("ii", Convert.ToString(listBox2.Items[ii]));
            }
            File.WriteAllText("latlong.txt", text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace replaces all occurrences, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net

Comment: How about `foreach(var element in listBox[1/2])` or `listBox[1/2].Items.ForEach(element =>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `Replace` is replacing all occurences of `ii`, so if you debug your loop you'll see that only the first time `ii`is replaced by the first item in your `listBox2`. To solve that,i think you should add the index to `ii`,something like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter stwr = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            stwr.WriteLine("googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(" + listBox1.Items[i] + ", " + "ii" + i + ")).title(" + "bbb" + "));");
        }
        stwr.Close();
        string text = File.ReadAllText("latlong.txt");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < listBox2.Items.Count; ii++)
        {

            text = text.Replace("ii"+ii, Convert.ToString(listBox2.Items[ii]));
        }
        File.WriteAllText("latlong.txt", text);
    }
}
```

Notice that in the first loop i'm adding `"ii" + i` and in the second i'm replacing `"ii"+ii`

Comment: Ahh that's great! I see where I went wrong, Thanks very much! :)