# what does FOO stand for?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'foo' really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean)

I hope it is not the most stupid question ever.

Whenever I read about javascript, I see people use the word **FOO**.

Where does this word come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as per wiki

The terms foobar /ˈfʊːbɑː/, fubar, or foo, bar, baz and qux (alternatively quux) are sometimes used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation.[1]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

http://catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html

Answer (score 9):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3092

Google is your best friend.

The origins of the terms are not known with certainty, and several anecdotal theories have been advanced to identify them. Foobar may have derived from the military acronym FUBAR and gained popularity because it is pronounced the same. In this meaning it also can derive from the German word furchtbar, which means awful and terrible.