# "foo" and "bar" used commonly in php.net and other sites

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'foo' really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean)

It is a very common thing to encounter in [php.net](http://php.net/) statements like `$foo="bar"` or other such statements. Is there any significance of `foo` and `bar` or are they just conventions evolved as a matter of time?

Comment: One quick wikipedia lookup away: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Comment: The creator was eating foo at bar.

Comment: @jdl lol, eating foo? btw, is foo some sort of an eatable?

Comment: & yeah, my bad. didn't notice its a duplicate..

Comment: Being at a bar, he was drunk... missed the 'd' when typing up his report, hence we know it as "foo"

Comment: the only convention i know of is that bar is generally used after foo in examples.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody's entirely certain of the origination of the two terms, but there are [theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar#History_and_etymology).

It's a lot like `Hello, world!`. It simply caught on.

Comment: No, we are actually "entirely certain".

Comment: Where did they originate, then?