# I have heard Foo a lot, what does it mean?

Tags: terminology, definition, metasyntactic-variable

Call me a noob, 'cause I really am, but what does 'foo' mean? I have seen it a lot. but I don't know what it means. Could someone clarify? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!  Remember, tags exist to help categorize questions.

Comment: @dvnrrs Oh sorry, i looked all over and didn't get that. thanks!

Comment: @Charles Thanks for fixing my tags!

Answer (score 2):

There is an an American military expression, `FUBAR`, which means "... beyond all recognition".  You can figure out what the FU means for yourself.  Programmers use the two syllables, `foo` and `bar` quite often for throw-away filenames, test programs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is used as a place-holder name, usually in example code to signify that the object being named, or the choice of name, is not part of the crux of the example. `foo` is often followed by `bar`, `baz`, and even `bundy`, if more than one such name is needed. Wikipedia calls these names [Metasyntactic Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). Python programmers supposedly use `spam`, `eggs`, `ham`, instead of `foo`, etc.

There are [good uses of foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683/using-in-to-match-an-attribute-of-python-objects-in-an-array#750:) in SA.

I have also seen `foo` used when the programmer can't think of a meaningful name (as a substitute for `tmp`, say), but I consider that to be a misuse of `foo`.

Edit= Will answered this on another question linked here.
I took this from this question: [What does 'foo' really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609/what-does-foo-really-mean)

Or you could use the internet slang term in which `foo` means `fool`.

Comment: -1, this is a verbatim copy of [this answer from the linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/58617/168868).  Copying without attribution and proper quoting is *plagiarism*.